# How is pre-computation handled by complexity notation?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Suppose I have an algorithm that runs in O(n) for every input of size n, but only after a pre-computation step of O(n^2) for that given size n.  Is the algorithm considered O(n) still, with O(n^2) amortized?  Or does big O only consider one "run" of the algorithm at size n, and so the pre-computation step is included in the notation, making the true notation O(n+n^2) or O(n^2)?

Comment: This is a theoretical question better suited for the [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com) exchange site.

Comment: Will post it there, thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not uncommon to see this accounted for by explicitly separating out the costs into two different pieces. For example, in the [range minimum query problem](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs166/cs166.1166/lectures/00/Slides00.pdf), it's common to see people talk about things like an ⟨O(n<sup>2</sup>), O(1)⟩-time solution to the problem, where the O(n<sup>2</sup>) denotes the precomputation cost and the O(1) denotes the lookup cost. You also see this with string algorithms sometimes: a [suffix tree provides an O(m)-preprocessing-time, O(n+z)-query-time solution to string searching](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs166/cs166.1166/lectures/03/Slides03.pdf), while [Aho-Corasick string matching offers an O(n)-preprocessing-time, O(m+z)-query-time solution](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs166/cs166.1166/lectures/02/Slides02.pdf).

The reason for doing so is that the tradeoffs involved here really depend on the use case. It lets you quantitatively measure how many queries you're going to have to make before the preprocessing time starts to be worth it.

Answer (score 2):

People usually care about the total time to get things done when they are talking about complexity etc.

Thus, if getting to the result `R` requires you to perform steps A and B, then `complexity(R) = complexity(A) + complexity(B)`. This works out to be `O(n^2)` in your particular example.

You have already noted that for `O` analysis, the fastest growing term dominates the overall complexity (or in other words, in a pipeline, the slowest module defines the throughput).

However, complexity analysis of `A` and `B` will be typically performed in isolation if they are disjoint.

In summary, it's the amount of time taken to get the results that counts, but you can (and usually do) reason about the individual steps independent of one another.

---

There are cases when you cannot only specify the slowest part of the pipeline. A simple example is BFS, with the complexity `O(V + E)`. Since `E = O(V^2)`, it may be tempting to write the complexity of BFS as `O(E)` (since `E > V`). However, that would be *incorrect*, since there can be a graph with no edges! In those cases, you will still need to iterate over all the vertices.

Answer (score 1):

The point of O(...) notation is not to measure how fast the algorithm is working, because in many specific cases O(n) can be significantly slower than, say O(n^3). (Imagine the algorithm which runs in 10^100 n steps vs. the one which runs in n^3 / 2 steps.) If I tell you that my algorithm runs in O(n^2) time, it tells you nothing about how long it will take for n = 1000.

The point of O(...) is to specify how the algorithm behaves when the input size grows. If I tell you that my algorithm runs in O(n^2) time, and it takes 1 second to run for n = 500, then you'll expect rather 4 seconds to for n = 1000, not 1.5 and not 40.

So, to answer your question -- no, the algorithm will not be O(n), it will be O(n^2), because if I double the input size the time will be multiplied by 4, not by 2.